# hp smart array lock up code 0x15, what is that? (or where can I get a list of descriptions of HP smart array controller lock up codes)

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I've had a couple of Dl180 6g boxes hung over the last week, each have a P410 smart array controller. upon reboot the server has indicated that a controller failure event occurred and the previous lock up code was 0x15 - the server rebooted without issue. However there was nothing in the IML log, but the ADU report provided the following;

```
Trap Address High Or Post Results Lockup Reason Or Post Error RIS Updates Or Post Error Detail Firmware Version Trap Address Low
0x8087 0x0015 0x0000033e 0x015e 0xd65c
```

any suggestions on what that code is, my google fu failed. And hp support have not responded with any detail as yet.

Comment: Did you ever determine what the code meant?

Answer (score 1):

HP doesn't publish the meaning of the lockup codes.  Usually, the code alone isn't enough to figure out what went wrong.  If you can get in touch with HP support, they'll probably have you send a complete ADU report.